# Combining .hover() and .replaceWith()

Tags: jquery

I can't get this simple `.replaceWith()` to co-operate with a `.hover()`. Would appreciate some help.

I want it the text to change to EXPAND when I hover on it, and go back to SHOWS when I mouseout.  I can get the text to change to EXPAND, but I can't get the text to go back to the original, SHOWS.

The [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sh95e/1/) code for anyone kind enough to have a look.

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
   $("p").hover(
      function () {
        $('#shows').replaceWith('<h2>Expand</h2>');
      }, 
      function () {
        $('#shows').replaceWith('<h2>Shows</h2>');
      }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is when you're replacing it it's losing the `id` attribute. So although the `mouseout` function of the `hover()` event fires it can't find the element `#shows`.

Try this instead:

```
// Change H1 text to "EXPAND" when hovered on, and go *back* to "SHOWS" when the mouse leaves

$(document).ready(function() {   
   $("p").hover(
      function () {
        $('#shows').text('Expand');
      },
      function () {
        $('#shows').text('Shows');
      }
    );
});
```

You should always use `.text()` or `.html()` in examples like this because acctually all you want to do is change the inner bit the TEXT or the HTML contained within the `<h2>` tag, rather than the whole element.

If you want to use replaceWith:

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
   $("p").hover(
      function () {
        $('#shows').replaceWith('<h2 id="shows">Expand</h2>');
      },
      function () {
        $('#shows').text('<h2 id="shows">Shows</h2>');
      }
    );
});
```

Comment: Awesome Thomas. Thanks thanks thanks. You helped fix an immediate problem with a dose of teaching at the end.  Thanks a million.

Comment: Rats! Forgot the one last part:  How would I animate the up/down motion I have setup on the footer here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GTwuC/1/)? 

This is really part of a larger part of jQuery that I've never been able to put together. I've never been able to figure out how to do things in sucession. IE: make the box go up and down is easy, but I can't see how you would put an `.animate()` in there along with it.  Thanks again for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

[**.replaceWith()**](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) will replace the original element (`#shows`) entirely --> no more element with `id=#shows` will be found (2nd try will fail).

What you want to do, is replace the inner html of `#shows` (using [**.html()**](http://api.jquery.com/html/)):

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
   $("p").hover(
      function () {
        $('#shows').html('<h2>Expand</h2>');
      }, 
      function () {
        $('#shows').html('<h2>Shows</h2>');
      }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

once you use `.replaceWith()` method, the element `#shows` no longer exists and cannot be replaced anymore :)