# Rearrange Text/Letters On Mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'd like for some text on my page to have the letters rearranged when a user hovers over it.  For example, mouseover "WORK," and it becomes "OWKR."  I suspect js is needed, but I'm still pretty new to js.  Below is my html:

```
<div class="header">
<div id="access" role="navigation">
<ul id="nav">
    <li id="work"><a href="work.html" title="Portfolio">WORK</a></li>
    <li id="studio"><a href="studio.html" title="About Us">STUDIO</a></li>
    <li id="contact"><a href="mailto:someone">CONTACT</a></li>
    <li id="news"><a href="news.html" title="Goings Ons">NEWS</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

I found a post that helped at [Combining .hover() and .replaceWith()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5992623/combining-hover-and-replacewith) and expanded that code for my list.  However, I have a feeling my js is not as clean as it could be and the other issue I'm having is that on mouseover, the text is no longer a link.  Here's my js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
   $("#work").hover(
      function () {
        $('#work').text('KROW');
      },
      function () {
        $('#work').text('WORK');
      }
    );
    $("#studio").hover(
      function () {
        $('#studio').text('DUTIOS');
      },
      function () {
        $('#studio').text('STUDIO');
      }
    );
    $("#contact").hover(
      function () {
        $('#contact').text('ANOTTCC');
      },
      function () {
        $('#contact').text('CONTACT');
      }
    );
    $("#news").hover(
      function () {
        $('#news').text('ENSW');
      },
      function () {
        $('#news').text('NEWS');
      }
    );
});
```

I know it's probably not great, but this was the only way I could get it to rearrange like I wanted.

[Here's the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/01x30fc4/5/)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: read this article it will help you http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/08/06/creative-link-effects/

Comment: Your above code will work perfect as you want. Only just give your 'li' id to a tag like <li><a id="work" href="work.html" title="Portfolio">WORK</a></li>  :)

Comment: yeah, i'm an idiot.  i simply added >a after work, contact, etc., in the js (like #work>a, #contact>a, etc.) and it works fine and retains the links.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one more way, You can associate data to all the anchor links and toggle the text on mouseover and mouseout event.

Here is the [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rd9bhrs6/).

You can just add one common class (e.g. "jumble-up-text") to these anchor links and bind "mouseover", "mouseout" event on it.

HTML :

```
<li><a class="jumble-up-text" href="work.html" title="Portfolio" data-changetxt="KROW">WORK</a></li>
```

Javascript :

```
$("a.jumble-up-text").on("mouseover mouseout", function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var sShowTxt = $this.data('changetxt');
    $this.data('changetxt', $this.text());   
    $this.text(sShowTxt);

});
```

This code will overwrite the anchor tag text on **mouseover** and set it back to its original value on **mouseout** event.

You can re-use the same code for other anchor links, you just have to attach same class and set the "data-changetxt" attribute value to the the text you want to display on mousehover.

Answer (score 3):

You can simple use the css property `content` to provide the same effect. It is easy to use.

`content:"YOUR TEXT"`

[Here is my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ccjfasxu/)

Check it and let me know if there any problem.